# How to animate side slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress, animation, slider

I need plugin/javascript for my wordpress which will allow me to show slided out divs. For example:

before hover
http://prntscr.com/9m4in3

after
http://prntscr.com/9m4jxe

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to show so people can help you with specific answers to a specific problem? Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JQuery? It is the most common js plugin for animations.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's Slide Effect will do what you need.

http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slide demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #toggle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<div id="toggle"></div>

<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```